# custom UIPickerView with one componenet in ios7

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

I used standard UIPickerView with one component to all the xib in the whole apps. so, i have written the UIPcikerview generation in all the pages but i need to create one custom UIPickerview with one component and i need to use that custom in all the pages in my whole apps with datasource and delegate in IOS7,

Comment: Your not asking a question. What is a custom UIPickerView ? what does it need to do ? what difficulty are you facing ? what have you tried so far ? have you researched or tried anything ? you need to answer all of these questions before anyone can help you

Answer (score 0):

You should either write your own or you can just use a one being described here.

[mmpickerview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mmpickerview)

[MMPickerView @GitHub](https://github.com/madjid/MMPickerView)

Hope that helps.